# Passing a certificate on a Python HTTP request

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

This post may be duplicated, but I'm trying to find the simplest way to perform a rest API request passing a certificate just like I do within Postman:

[Cert configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gUpJ.png)

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAyk.png)

Comment: Use `requests` package. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you @ypnos, but I'm having a real had time trying to pass the .pem (put the .p12 version of it on the prints not sure why xD), the private key and it's passphrase. Using requests it says "Client private key is encrypted, password is required" and now I'm stuck and the docs didn't help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the those of you in the future looking for the easiest solution, I found this thread on GitHub that solved my issue:

https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1573#issuecomment-348968658

Was able to get the response I was wishing for.